# how to save listbox items in text file?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to save ListBox items in text file.
The Items I have added from properties:

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (FileStream S = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                    using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
                        foreach (string aa in listBox1.Items)
                            st.WriteLine(listBox1.Items);
            }
        }
```

The output in text file is: System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection

Comment: Change `st.Writeline(listBox1.Items);` to `st.Writeline(aa);` since you want the individual items to be written to the file.

Comment: did not notice that. thanks : ))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @davidsbro mentioned, you want `aa` to be in the `st.Writeline` as that is the actual string. listBox1.Items gives a class which Writeline can't handle as it doesn't know what you would want from `Items`. So it outputs the name which is the result you got. If you want all the properties and other information about that `Items` class you would have to serialize it and write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `aa` into writeLine

```
               if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (FileStream S = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
                         {
                            foreach (var aa in listBox1.Items)
                                st.WriteLine(aa.ToString());
                         }
                    }
                }
```